# Python: Memory Leak

Tags: python, memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, garbage

I'm using Python to display a bitmap image on a LCD display (Raspberry Pi). This works quite well but it seems that I've created myself a huge memory leak.
This piece of code seems to be the culprit:

```
def displayBitmap(self):
    spi.open(0,0)
    f = open("data/565.bmp", "rb")
    imgdata = f.read()
    f.close()

    self.setAddress(0, 0, LCD_WIDTH-1, LCD_HEIGHT-1)
    k = 0
    for i in range(0, (LCD_WIDTH*LCD_HEIGHT)):
        dt = (ord(imgdata[k]) | (ord(imgdata[k+1]) << 8))

        self.spiOutData(dt,2)
        k +=2
    imgdata = None
    spi.close()
```

...

```
def spiOutData(self, data, bytes=1):
    io.digitalWrite(15, io.LOW)
    io.digitalWrite(16, io.HIGH)

    io.digitalWrite(self.dcPin, io.HIGH)

    if (bytes == 1):
        spi.xfer2([(data)])
    else:
        spi.xfer2([(data>>8)])
        spi.xfer2([(data)])
```

It runs fine for some time, but at some point it terminates due to lack of memory. My guess is that the contents of `imgdata` never get deleted but my Python knowledge seems to be too bad to be able to find the reason. 
Could you give me a hint, please? Thank you very much.

Comment: `imgdata = None` this is *utterly* useless. Python has its own garbage collector which *does* know how to do its job. When the function finishes that reference will be deleted anyway so that kind of statements have the *only* effect of *slowing down* your code a bit. Maybe the data in `imgdata` isn't being deallocated but you can be 100% sure that it's *not* fault of that reference. There may be other parts of your program that somehow grab a reference to it (although strange). -1 for not providing the full traceback.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought so and I only added `imgdata = None` for testing purposes because, as I said, I'm pretty clueless. Here's the whole code but what I've posted really is pretty much everything that happens: http://nopaste.info/9c65fb9840.html I can't provide the traceback right now as it takes quite some time for the memory to get full, but I will provide it as soon as it occurs again.

Comment: For anyone who runs into the same problem: it seems to be due to a bug in the `spidev` library. (The call to `spi.xfer2` causes the memory leak)

Comment: If you are sure of that you should post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is what I have found out:

- the `py-spidev` module (or some part of spidev itself) seems to be the problem.
- besides the memory leak, `py-spidev` is incredibly slow

I've now got rid of `py-spidev` and write to `/dev/spidev0.0` directly via file handle. No more excessive memory usage and SPI communication now needs about two seconds, that's about a tenth of the time it needed before.

Comment: This bug seems to resolved in version 3.5 of the `spidev` package with this change: https://github.com/doceme/py-spidev/pull/57/files